# Downloading old version of any app in iPhone 8?

Tags: ios-appstore

I want to download the old version of Musically app on my iPhone 8. Please let us know the steps to download the old version of the app. I can only download the latest version of apps from the app store. Can we download the older version in the new phone?

Answer (score 3):

The following solution only works if you once installed the app at the version you want, synced with the older version of iTunes (12.6.4.3 or below), didn't update in iTunes.

You can also look through Time Machine backup in the

`/[iTunes Library Directory]/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications` directory

1. Plug in your iOS device
2. Select "Apps" and view all the apps in **your** (not the iOS device) app library [image].
3. Drag one of the apps onto the iOS device listed in the side bar
4. Wait for sync to finish
5. Celebrate

Additionally, you can look through iPhone backups.

Comment: I have backed app my iPhone on iTunes 12.8.0.150. Can I still get the old app from there somehow? If not, how can I access it through time-machine? I'm pretty sure I have the app there somewhere...

Comment: That directory should be covered by Time Machine so you can restore and search for old apps using spotlight and time machine @bobsacameno

Answer (score 2):

Once a new version of an app is released on the App Store, there is no way to access the older version. You may choose to not update to the newly released version, but once upgraded there is no going back.

This is true for any app on the App Store. A major purpose of releasing an update is to provide improved functionalities and fix issues with the previous version.

Comment: “There’s no [official] way”