# Old Versions in app store

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore

I can't find any way to access the older versions.

Is it in any way possible to download an older version of an app on App Store to support an older operating system?

Comment: Check this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/195074/30895 and this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/385193/30895

Comment: Only if you have already purchased the app.

Answer (score 3):

Purchasing old versions is nearly impossible, but some have managed it before in the past using computers and other devices if your device won’t let a purchase happen. I don’t expect you’ll have any luck in 2024 with this.

If [the developer leaves the app up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/195097/5472), Apple will still serve and sign the older versions of apps. This works well for [apps you have already purchased](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/385193/5472). Re-downloading is much easier than purchasing these apps and only the developer seems to prevent this if they choose not to allow it. Apple supports this for apps I purchased in the first days of the iOS App Store.

[Some people go so far as to sync and archive the IPA files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/325913/5472) so they can jailbreak and side load apps or see if they can sync with official tools the versions they prefer, but this can be highly technical and goes deeper than “download” an old version.